# Errors that i don't know how to solve with standard component for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The unity standard component comes pre-packaged with errors on visual studio and im trying to learn so I tried playing around with the auto-correct system and got it down to the fewest errors I could.

I made sure I have the most up to date unity and VisualStudio with all relevant plugins.

https://gist.github.com/EgoSphere001/288818beb7ad0d2db2bdda028508c76e

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to include all information when asking a question, like what you are trying to achieve, your code, and what output you get, and why it is not what you want.

Comment: I have never seen the errors you are talking about the comes "pre-packaged"  I would recommend possibly uninstalling and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at your script again

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement()
    {
    }
}

public Rigidbody rb;
// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start() => Debug.Log("Hello, World!");

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{

}
```

You are closing the `PlayerMovement` class ... so where does `rb` and `Update` belong to?! You expression body for `Start` is ok-ish but I would suggest to stick with a normal method declaration.

Also MonoBehaviours can not be generated using a constructor so the `public PlayerMovement(){` makes no sense either.

---

Your script should probably look like this

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

---

Also note: You should remove any empty Unity messages like `Update`, `Start` etc .. because Unity calls them anyway causing unnecessary overhead.